# How to install java for firefox in unix?

Tags: java, linux

I need to run java applet in my Linux machine. So I tried the steps in java.com to install JRE. What should I do after extracting JRE .tar file.I want the java to be available in my Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not looking for JRE, but instead to install the JVM Java install. ie. 'Java 8 update 56' (or the simplified revision download) etc. rather than JRE 8.56.#... **Note:** The differences in both installs is quite small, but should follow the same steps either way.

[The official home of Java and respective download links.](https://www.java.com/en/)

It should be as simple as following the install requirements here. Download the RPM and as an administrator account run (replacing rpm location):

> rpm -i /path/to/java.rpm

[More information on installing the Java RPM](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#rpm)

**Edit:** If using Ubuntu, there's a perfect answer for this over in the  [Ubuntu distro forum.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: `rpm` migjt not work well on Debian based distributions (e.g. Ubuntu)

Comment: If using Ubuntu, there's a perfect answer for this over in the  [Ubuntu distro forum.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)